Why code doesn't reach last column in matrix?
I had to write code in C# that should determine the minimum and maximum in all even and odd columns, but the code does not include the last column at all, which in case the matrix is ​​3*4, would be odd. it does not check the numbers in the last column at all.
int min_o = Int32.MaxValue;
int max_o = Int32.MinValue;
int min_e = Int32.MaxValue;
int max_e = Int32.MinValue;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 != 0) 
        {
            if (a[i, j] < min_o)
                min_o = a[i, j];
            else if (a[i, j] > max_o)
                max_o = a[i, j];
        }
        else 
        {
            if (a[i, j] < min_e)
                min_e = a[i, j];
            else if (a[i, j] > max_e)
                max_e = a[i, j];
        }
    }
}

max_o and min_o are used for maximum and minimum for odd columns, and max_e and min_e are used for even columns.
here is example of what input and output for my program is:
n: 3
m: 4
1 2 3 4
5 4 6 7
9 1 7 9

Minimum for odd columns is: 1, maximum for odd columns is: 4Minimum for even columns is: 1, maximum for even columns is: 9

I tried to input 4*5 matrix, so that last column can be even, because I thought, maybe there is a problem when the last column is odd, but same problem is there too.

You should also include the declarations of n, m and a, because they are relevant for your problem.

I think it's because you are using n in the inner for loop rather than m (assuming n is the number of rows and m is the number of columns)
I should be
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)

NOT
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

